# I got error when I converted my html template into react in the javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

The error is
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Code:

```
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";   //Error is showed at this line  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

I included my script tag in index.html of public folder
Rest javascript files are working except this

Answer (score 0):

const mystyle = {
display: "block",
};

Answer (score 0):

const mystyle = {
display: "block",
};

```html
  const mystyle = {
    display: "block",
  };

  <div className="Works" style={slideIndex == 0 ? mystyle : null}></div>
```

Comment: This isn't working.....